# How to make Ruby 2.2 Rational#to_s show only numerator when denominator is 1

Tags: ruby

In earlier versions of Ruby `puts Rational(5)` used to produce `5` as the output.  With Ruby 2.x it always shows the denominator, even when it's 1.  Is there a way to monkey patch the `Rational` class to recover the old behavior?  I know I could write a new function such as

```
class Rational
  def esthetic_to_s
    denominator == 1 ? numerator.to_s : to_s
  end
end
```

to get the desired behavior

```
puts 5r.esthetic_to_s       # => 5
puts 1.5r.esthetic_to_s     # => 3/2
```

but I'd still have to explicitly invoke it.  I'd much rather be able to just say

```
puts 5r        # => 5
puts 1.5r      # => 3/2
```

and have it work as indicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could modify `Rational#to_s` directly, by using `alias`:

```
class Rational
  alias old_to_s to_s
  def to_s
    denominator == 1 ? numerator.to_s : old_to_s
  end
end
```

Comment: That's a winner!  I didn't know you could use aliasing to slide the old method aside.

Comment: That's what `prepend` is for, without needlessly polluting the namespace with `old_*` methods.

Answer (score 1):

You can refine `Rational#to_s` to do what you want, without globally affecting its behavior:

```
module RationalRefinement
  module PrettyToS
    def to_s
      if denominator == 1 then numerator.to_s else super end
    end
  end

  refine Rational do
    prepend PrettyToS
  end
end

1.to_r.to_s
# => '1/1'

using RationalRefinement

1.to_r.to_s
# => '1'

module RefinementsAreLexicallyScopedNotGlobal
  puts 1.to_r
  # 1/1
end
```

Comment: This looks quite elegant, but doesn't work for me.  On my machine (Ruby 2.2.2) copying and pasting into irb still yields '1/1' in all cases.

Comment: I just checked, and it works with Ruby 2.0 but not 2.2.